# charAt not working on element created dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, charat

I am Making a name searching app in javascript. I have created all list items dynamically in javascript.

**[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y14fw7ok/)**

And when I use charAt(0) the app is not working nothing is displaying
I want to match the first chracter of input and first character of array

```js
names = ["Ayesha", "Alina", "Bilal", "Kaira", "Per", "Henry", "Liba", "Rimsha"]

let ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el")
let searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput");

function render(things) {
  let listItems = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
    listItems += `
            <li class="names">
                    ${things[i]}
            </li>
        `
  }
  ulEl.innerHTML = listItems
}

render(names)

searchInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  let searchQuery = event.target.value.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
  let allNamesDOMCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('names');

  console.log(allNamesDOMCollection.textContent)


  console.log(allNamesDOMCollection.textContent)
  for (let i = 0; i < allNamesDOMCollection.length; i++) {
    let currentName = allNamesDOMCollection[i].textContent.toLowerCase().charAt(0);


    if (currentName.includes(searchQuery)) {
      allNamesDOMCollection[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      allNamesDOMCollection[i].style.display = "none";
    }

  }
})
```

```html
<h1>Search Names</h1>

<div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search">
</div>

<div class="container cont-modifier">

  <ul id="ul-el"></ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Please use the **on-site** Stack Snippets feature rather than off-site resources.  [Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, you need to loop through it's values, `console.log(allNamesDOMCollection[0].textContent)` works for exemple

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy - It returns an `HTMLCollection`, not an array. In their actual code, they're looping through, it's only that `console.log` that they don't.

Comment: Yea what I meant is that it's not a fixed defined value. He's asking why it's returning undefined, I just explained :)

Comment: Why are you getting just the **first** character of each name in the list? Your search field allows more than one...

Comment: @T.J Crowder  I want to match the first chracter of input and first character of array to display the names that start with it

Comment: the `textContent` of your elements starts with a bunch of whitespaces, thus `textContent.charA(0) == ' '`. You probably want to trim it before, or remove the whitespaces while you create the element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `undefined` thing is because the `HTMLCollection` returned by `getElementsByClassName` has no `textContent` property, but since that's just in your `console.log` we can largely disregard that.

The main problem is that the first character of the list items is a whitespace character because of how you build the `listItems` string, you need to `trim()` the text content if you want the first character of the name. (Or change how you build `listItems`.)

I also suggest using the `input` event, not `keyup`.

It seems odd that your search input allows multiple characters but you're only using the first, but you confirmed in a comment that's what you wanted, so I've left it that way — but see the end of the answer for how to do a full match if you prefer.

See `***` comments:

```js
// *** Add a declaration
const names = ["Ayesha", "Alina", "Bilal", "Kaira", "Per", "Henry", "Liba", "Rimsha"];

let ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el");
let searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput");

function render(things) {
    let listItems = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
        listItems += `
            <li class="names">
                    ${things[i]}
            </li>
        `;
    }
    ulEl.innerHTML = listItems;
}

render(names);

// *** Use `input`, not `keyup`
searchInput.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
    let searchQuery = event.target.value.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
    let allNamesDOMCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('names');

    for (let i = 0; i < allNamesDOMCollection.length; i++) {
        // *** Remove the whitespace before getting first character
        let currentName = allNamesDOMCollection[i].textContent.trim().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^
        if (currentName.includes(searchQuery)) {
            allNamesDOMCollection[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            allNamesDOMCollection[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<h1>Search Names</h1>

<div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search">
</div>

<div class="container cont-modifier">

  <ul id="ul-el"></ul>

</div>
```

Alternatively, change how you build `listItems`:

```
function render(things) {
    let listItems = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
        listItems += `<li class="names">${things[i]}</li>`; // *** Remove whitespace around name
    }
    ulEl.innerHTML = listItems;
}
```

Live Copy:

```js
// *** Add a declaration
const names = ["Ayesha", "Alina", "Bilal", "Kaira", "Per", "Henry", "Liba", "Rimsha"];

let ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el");
let searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput");

function render(things) {
    let listItems = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
        listItems += `<li class="names">${things[i]}</li>`; // *** Remove whitespace around name
    }
    ulEl.innerHTML = listItems;
}

render(names);

// *** Use `input`, not `keyup`
searchInput.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
    let searchQuery = event.target.value.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
    let allNamesDOMCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('names');

    for (let i = 0; i < allNamesDOMCollection.length; i++) {
        let currentName = allNamesDOMCollection[i].textContent.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        if (currentName.includes(searchQuery)) {
            allNamesDOMCollection[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            allNamesDOMCollection[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<h1>Search Names</h1>

<div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search">
</div>

<div class="container cont-modifier">

  <ul id="ul-el"></ul>

</div>
```

---

A couple of other side notes. When deal with natural language text, in general it's best to:

- Prefer [`toLocaleLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase) (and `toLocaleUpperCase()`) to their non-locale-specific versions.
- Use [`normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) (in environments where it's supported) to normalize any sequences of combining characters, etc., so you aren't hit by false negatives because the same glyph (`ç`, for instance) is written in different ways (`ç` [the "c-cedilla" code point, [U+00E7](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=00E7)] and `ç` [a `c` followed by a cedilla/cédille combining mark ([U+0327](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=0327)], for instance, which look almost the same but are not the same sequence of code points). If you don't normalize, for instance, and the user types in `Franç` (for example) using the single code point, it won't find `François` in the list if it's written with a `c` and a combining mark:

```js
let input = `Franç`;
let name = "François";
console.log(name.includes(input)); // false
input = input.normalize();
name = name.normalize();
console.log(name.includes(input)); // true
```

---

In a comment you asked what you'd change if you **did** want to check the entire input against the entire name. To do that, just remove the two `.charAt(0)` calls, if you want to match anywhere in the name. If you only want to match at the start of the name, use `startsWith` instead of `includes`.

Here's the above, using:

- `includes` to match anywhere in the name
- `toLocaleLowerCase` and `normalize`
- `for-of` (ES2015+) rather than `for` since it's a bit more convenient
- a class rather than inline styles to hide names

```js
const names = ["Ayesha", "Alina", "Bilal", "Kaira", "Per", "Henry", "Liba", "Rimsha"];

const ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el");
const searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput");

function render(things) {
    let listItems = "";
    for (const thing of things) {
        listItems += `
            <li class="names">
                    ${thing}
            </li>
        `;
    }
    ulEl.innerHTML = listItems;
}

render(names);

function prepForCompare(str) {
    str = str.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
    // `normalize` is newer than most of the rest of what we're using
    if (str.normalize) {
        str = str.normalize();
    }
    return str;
}

searchInput.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
    const searchQuery = prepForCompare(event.target.value);
    const allNamesDOMCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("names");
    for (const li of allNamesDOMCollection) {
        const currentName = prepForCompare(li.textContent);
        li.classList.toggle("hidden", !currentName.includes(searchQuery));
    }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Search Names</h1>

<div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search">
</div>

<div class="container cont-modifier">

  <ul id="ul-el"></ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working now. Can you also tell me how to match multiple characters? It was my mistake that I only was allowing to match the first character

Comment: @coder - Just remove the two `.charAt(0)` calls, and you're good to go, if you want to match anywhere in the name. If you only want to match at the **start** of the name, use `startsWith` instead of `includes`. But see the notes I've added to the end of the answer.

Comment: @coder - You're welcome! Glad that helps. I added an example to the end of doing matching on multiple strings, and incorporating those other notes.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the for loop with `forEach`, since what you were trying to do was to apply same lines of code to each element (pretty much what `forEach` does).

Your code doesn't work for multiple characters since you only compare 1st char. Remove both of `charAt(0)` and it should work just fine.

```js
names = ["Ayesha", "Alina", "Bilal", "Kaira", "Per", "Henry", "Liba", "Rimsha"]

let ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el")
let searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput");

function render(things) {
  let listItems = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
    listItems += `<li class="names">${things[i]}</li>`
  }
  ulEl.innerHTML = listItems;
}

render(names)

searchInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  let searchQuery = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
  let allNamesDOMCollection = document.querySelectorAll('.names');


  allNamesDOMCollection.forEach(e => {
    let currentName = e.innerText.toLowerCase();
    if (searchQuery == "") {
      e.style.display = "block";
    } else if (currentName.includes(searchQuery)) {
      e.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      e.style.display = "none";
    }

  })
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #A1FFCE;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FAFFD1, #A1FFCE);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FAFFD1, #A1FFCE);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  color: #363635;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cont-modifier {
  height: 550px;
  overflow: auto;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #595A4A;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  background-image: url('search-line.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.names {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0b1354;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Search Names</h1>

<div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search">
</div>

<div class="container cont-modifier">

  <ul id="ul-el"></ul>

</div>
```

---

If you want 'strict' checking (for ex: currently, typing 'A' also shows 'Kaira', 'Bilal' etc.), you can add another condition where it will check if 1st char matches or not.

```js
names = ["Ayesha", "Alina", "Bilal", "Kaira", "Per", "Henry", "Liba", "Rimsha"]

let ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el")
let searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput");

function render(things) {
  let listItems = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
    listItems += `<li class="names">${things[i]}</li>`
  }
  ulEl.innerHTML = listItems;
}

render(names)

searchInput.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  let searchQuery = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
  let allNamesDOMCollection = document.querySelectorAll('.names');


  allNamesDOMCollection.forEach(e => {
    let currentName = e.innerText.toLowerCase();

    if (searchQuery == "") {
      e.style.display = "block";
    } else if (currentName.includes(searchQuery) && currentName[0] === searchQuery[0]) {
      e.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      e.style.display = "none";
    }

  })
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #A1FFCE;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FAFFD1, #A1FFCE);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FAFFD1, #A1FFCE);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  color: #363635;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cont-modifier {
  height: 550px;
  overflow: auto;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #595A4A;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  background-image: url('search-line.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.names {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0b1354;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Search Names</h1>

<div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search">
</div>

<div class="container cont-modifier">

  <ul id="ul-el"></ul>

</div>
```

Comment: @coder Based on what you were trying to do, I think you should take a look at second part of my answer.